# Persist ASP.NET Core 3.1 identity external login authentication cookie across sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity in my .NET Core 3.1 project and having a hard time figuring out how to persist cookies created from external login providers such as Microsoft or Google across sessions. So far the cookie is always a session cookie and no matter which extension point I've tried, nothing changed that.

Inspecting the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L140), one could assume that the following approach should work, but it doesn't:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
    {
        ...

        options.Events.OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
            ctx.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

The event handler gets invoked sucessfully but the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` cookie remains unchanged. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something pretty substantial here - aka digging at the wrong spot :)